Invalid argument: required broadcastable shapes at loc(unknown)
I am new to DL and trying to develop an encoder-decoder with attention. When I train, it will stop just before the end of the first epoch, I guess the problem happens when the loss function tries to compare the labels and predictions.
My labels are shape: (batch_size, 500, 65)
This is the error I get:
110/111 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 3.3515 - categorical_accuracy: 0.3146
2024-11-13 12:53:13.805510: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1755] Invalid argument: required broadcastable shapes at loc(unknown)
Here I generate the inputs, I plan to implement teacher forcing in the future but decoder input is not important right now.
max_input_sequence = 500
input_dimension = 26
LSTMoutputDimension = 65
output_dimension = 65

#Prepare TRAIN data set
encoder_input_data = X_train.copy()
decoder_target_data = y_train.copy()
decoder_input_data = decoder_target_data.copy()
for i, samples in enumerate(decoder_target_data):
  seq = one_hot_decode(samples)
  shifted= shift(seq, 1, cval=0)
  decoder_input_data[i]=one_hot_encode(shifted,output_dimension)
print("Data for Train")
print('encoder_input_data (X): ', one_hot_decode(encoder_input_data[1]))
print('decoder_input_data (teacher forcing): ',one_hot_decode(decoder_input_data[1]))
print('decoder_target_data (y):',one_hot_decode(decoder_target_data[1]))
print(encoder_input_data.shape)

#Prepare TEST data set
encoder_input_test = X_test.copy()
decoder_target_test = y_test.copy()
decoder_input_test= decoder_target_test.copy()
for i, samples in enumerate(decoder_target_test):
  seq = one_hot_decode(samples)
  shifted= shift(seq, 1, cval=0)
  decoder_input_test[i]=one_hot_encode(shifted,output_dimension)

This is the code that generates the model.
verbose= 0
batch_size=32

#See all debug messages

if verbose:
  print('***** Model Hyper Parameters *******')
  print('latentSpaceDimension: ', LSTMoutputDimension)
  print('batch_size: ', batch_size)
  print('sequence length: ', max_input_sequence)
  print('n_features: ', input_dimension)

  print('\n***** TENSOR DIMENSIONS *******')


# The first part is encoder
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(max_input_sequence, input_dimension), name='encoder_inputs')
masking = tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value= [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
encoder_inputs_masked = masking(encoder_inputs)
encoder_lstm=LSTM(LSTMoutputDimension, return_state=True, return_sequences = True, name='encoder_lstm')
LSTM_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder_lstm(encoder_inputs_masked)


if verbose:
  print ('Encoder output shape: (batch size, sequence length, latentSpaceDimension) {}'.format(LSTM_outputs.shape))
  print ('Encoder Hidden state shape: (batch size, latentSpaceDimension) {}'.format(state_h.shape))
  print ('Encoder Cell state shape: (batch size, latentSpaceDimension) {}'.format(state_c.shape))

encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

if verbose:
  print(encoder_states)

attention= BahdanauAttention(LSTMoutputDimension, verbose=verbose)


decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(1, (65+LSTMoutputDimension)),name='decoder_inputs')
decoder_lstm = LSTM(LSTMoutputDimension, return_state=True, name='decoder_lstm')
decoder_dense = Dense(output_dimension, activation='softmax', name='decoder_dense')

all_outputs = []

inputs = np.zeros((batch_size, 1,65 ))
inputs[:, 0, 0] = 1 

decoder_outputs = state_h
states = encoder_states

if verbose:
  print('initial decoder inputs: ', inputs.shape)


# decoder will only process one time step at a time.
for _ in range(500):


    # 3 pay attention
    # create the context vector by applying attention to 
    # decoder_outputs (last hidden state) + encoder_outputs (all hidden states)
    context_vector, attention_weights=attention(decoder_outputs, LSTM_outputs)
    if verbose:
      print("Attention context_vector: (batch size, units) {}".format(context_vector.shape))
      print("Attention weights : (batch_size, sequence_length, 1) {}".format(attention_weights.shape))
      print('decoder_outputs: (batch_size,  latentSpaceDimension) ', decoder_outputs.shape )

    context_vector = tf.expand_dims(context_vector, 1)
    if verbose:
      print('Reshaped context_vector: ', context_vector.shape )

    # 4. concatenate the input + context vectore to find the next decoder's input
    inputs = tf.concat([context_vector, inputs], axis=-1)
    
    if verbose:
      print('After concat inputs: (batch_size, 1, n_features + hidden_size): ',inputs.shape )

    # 5. passing the concatenated vector to the LSTM
    # Run the decoder on one timestep with attended input and previous states
    decoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = decoder_lstm(inputs,
                                            initial_state=states)
    #decoder_outputs = tf.reshape(decoder_outputs, (-1, decoder_outputs.shape[2]))
  
    outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
    # 6. Use the last hidden state for prediction the output
    # save the current prediction
    # we will concatenate all predictions later
    outputs = tf.expand_dims(outputs, 1)
    all_outputs.append(outputs)
    # 7. Reinject the output (prediction) as inputs for the next loop iteration
    # as well as update the states
    inputs = outputs
    states = [state_h, state_c]


# 8. After running Decoder for max time steps
# we had created a predition list for the output sequence
# convert the list to output array by Concatenating all predictions 
# such as [batch_size, timesteps, features]
decoder_outputs = Lambda(lambda x: K.concatenate(x, axis=1))(all_outputs)

# 9. Define and compile model 
model_encoder_decoder_Bahdanau_Attention = Model(encoder_inputs, 
                                                 decoder_outputs, name='model_encoder_decoder')
model_encoder_decoder_Bahdanau_Attention.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', 
                                                 loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

This is the training line:
model_encoder_decoder_Bahdanau_Attention.fit(encoder_input_data, decoder_target_data,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=2, validation_split = 0.1)

